# My Flutter code returns "The method 'listItem' isn't defined for the type '_FitnessAppState'"

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is the main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: FitnessApp(),
    );
  }
}

class FitnessApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FitnessAppState createState() => _FitnessAppState();
}

class _FitnessAppState extends State<FitnessApp> {
  String img_Header = "https://unsplash.com/photos/fG0p4Qh_aWI";

  List<String> trainingImage = [
    "https://unsplash.com/photos/Jc-UCKGhIlU"
        "https://unsplash.com/photos/WvDYdXDzkhs"
        "https://unsplash.com/photos/Lx_GDv7VA9M"
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 300.0,
              pinned: false,
              floating: false,
              title: Text(
                "FitApp",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              centerTitle: true,
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              toolbarHeight: 80.0,
              leading: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
              ),
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                background: Image.network(
                  img_Header,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  color: Color(0xaa212121),
                  colorBlendMode: BlendMode.darken,
                ),
              ),
              bottom: PreferredSize(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: 24.0, left: 12.0, right: 12.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      ),
                      contentPadding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0, horizontal: 24.0),
                      hintText: "Search for the training program...",
                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.search,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(80.0),
              ),
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ];
        },
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, right: 20.0, left: 20.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Top Trends",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 24.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20.0,
                ),
                listItem(trainingImage[0], "Full Body Program", 53, 30),
                listItem(trainingImage[1], "Yoga Training", 30, 10),
                listItem(trainingImage[2], "Full Body ", 53, 30),
                listItem(trainingImage[3], "Full Body Program", 53, 30),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the listitem.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget listItem(String bg, String title, int exercises, int time) {
  return Container(
    width: double.infinity,,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: NetworkImage(bg),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Color(0x60212121), BlendMode.darken),
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    ),
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            title, 
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white, 
            fontSize: 24.0, 
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0,
          ),
          Text(
            "${exercices} Exercices", 
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white, 
            fontSize: 18.0, 
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 4.0,
          ),
           Text(
            "${time} Minutes Per Day", 
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white, 
            fontSize: 18.0, 
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
}
```

---

1. the images are not loading it's just black or nonexistent
2. List item is being pulled from another page called listitem.dart
   but has a error saying : The method 'listItem' isn't defined for the
   type '_FitnessAppState'. Try correcting the name to the name of an
   existing method, or defining a method named
   'listItem'.dart(undefined_method)

Comment: 1. check again if the link in trainingImage is an image link or not. 2. either you add listitem to main.dart page, or import it

Answer (score 0):

It may be some broken link or something. The list item is not defined for class fitnessApp. Instead of creating a Widget try creating a class extending statefullWidget and finalise variables with objects

```
class ListItem extends StatefulWidget {
 final bg;
 final title;
 final exercises;
 final time;

 ListItem({this.bg, this.title, this.exercises, this.time});

  @override
  _ListItem State createState() => _ListItem State();
}

class _ListItem State extends State<ListItem > {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
    width: double.infinity,,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: NetworkImage(bg),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Color(0x60212121), BlendMode.darken),
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    ),
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            title, 
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white, 
            fontSize: 24.0, 
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0,
          ),
          Text(
            "${exercices} Exercices", 
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white, 
            fontSize: 18.0, 
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 4.0,
          ),
           Text(
            "${time} Minutes Per Day", 
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white, 
            fontSize: 18.0, 
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
  }
}
```

Try doing this and import this file to your fitness app file and call ListItem there you will see the variables there to fill out.